# Umgang mit Beiträgen, die die Frage nicht beantworten

Tags: discussion

Wie geht man mit Beiträgen um, die die Frage gar nicht beantworten?

- Ignorieren?
- Abwerten?
- Als *not an answer* markieren?
- Etwas anderes?

**Hintergrund:**

Zur Frage [What is the correct way to say “and the last is“?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/65224/25241), in dem es um das Geschlecht des Artikels in einem bestimmten Ausdruck geht, gibt es bis dato 5 Beiträge. Doch 3 davon beantworten gar nicht die Frage, sondern beschäftigen sich damit, wie man es anders formulieren kann. Da diese Beiträge eher (durchaus nützliche) Kommentare denn Antworten sind, habe ich (vorerst nur) einen von ihnen mit *not an answer* markiert. Die Markierung wurde jedoch abgelehnt.

Answer (score 4):

Manche (viele) Fragen (typisch "XY-Probleme") lassen sich auch gar nicht "ordentlich" beantworten, sondern es ist dann auch durchaus sinnvoll, Alternativen vorzuschlagen. Die Antwort sollte dabei aber trotzdem auf die ursprüngliche Frage eingehen und diesen Sachverhalt beleuchten.

Ein stoisches "beantwortet die Frage nicht"-Ablehnen würde speziellin solchen Situationen das Kind mit dem Bade ausschütten.

Answer (score 2):

Das Markieren als "not an answer" hat verschiedene mögliche Ursachen, die meiner Meinung nach auch verschieden behandelt werden sollten.

- Der klassische Vertreter stammt von einem neuen Beitragenden, der einen Kommentar oder eine verwandte Frage als Antwort ausgibt: Hier ist die Markierung sinnvoll, möglicherweise kombiniert mit einem Kommentar, der den Autoren informiert. Ein Moderator kann die "Antwort" dann in einen Kommentar umwandeln oder löschen.
- Schrott aller Art, Spam, sowie Antworten, die keinen Bezug zur gestellten Frage haben. Bitte ebenfalls markieren, die werden typischerweise recht zügig gelöscht.
- Bei allem anderen, also bei Antworten, die dem geneigten Leser nicht hinreichend exakt zur Frage zu passen scheinen oder ihm/ihr wichtige Aspekte unberücksichtigt lassen, sehe ich oft keine sinnvolle Moderatorenaktion. Solche Antworten sind, wenn schon nicht dem Autoren der Frage, dann vielleicht für andere Leser,  die eine ähnliche Frage haben, hilfreich. Eine deutlich positive Gesamtbewertung der Antwort ist ein Indiz für diesen Fall. Hier sehe ich als Reaktionsmöglichkeiten seitens des Anstoß Nehmenden hauptsächlich Kommentieren oder Abwerten. Der Moderator könnte nur Umwandeln in einen Kommentar, was nicht zur Situation passt, oder die Antwort löschen, was zu drastisch erscheint und möglicherweise die Bereitschaft zum Schreiben künftiger Antworten reduziert.

Besonders knifflig wird der Umgang mit der Markierung, wenn die Frage zudem etwas unklar ist, so dass der Antwortende da Annahmen treffen muss.

Siehe auch die verwandten Fragen:

- [When should the "Not an Answer" flag be used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107216/when-should-the-not-an-answer-flag-be-used)
- [How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag)

(Mir war nicht bewusst, dass das Ablehnen einer solchen Markierung mit einem Bewertungsmalus für den Markierer verbunden ist; ich werde künftig eher zu *helpful, but no further action required* tendieren.)

Answer (score 2):

Dem stimme ich zu. Manche Fragesteller gehen von Prämissen aus, die schlichtweg nicht zutreffen. Plakatives Beispiel: *»Warum ist der Mond aus Käse?«* - Nachdem der Mond nicht aus Käse ist, ist es unmöglich, eine korrekte Begründung zu liefern. Die gestellte Frage kann gar nicht korrekt beantwortet werden. In so einem Fall geht es gar nicht anders, als den Fragesteller auf die falsche Annahme aufmerksam zu machen und eine Antwort zu geben, die der eigentlichen Intention der Frage möglichst nahe kommt.

Wenn jemand fragt, warum der Mond aus Käse ist, könnte man jede beliebige Antwort von vorn herein als *»not an answer«* markieren, ohne sie überhaupt zu lesen. Das ist wohl nicht der Sinn der Sache.

Die von mir hier gewählte Mond-Frage ist natürlich ganz offensichtlich Unfug, man müsste die Frage selbst schließen. Aber bei vielen hier tatsächlich gestellten Fragen ist das nicht der Fall. Die/der FragestellerIn hat oftmals ein berechtigtes und nachvollziehbares Interesse an einer Beantwortung der Frage. Dass er/sie von falschen Annahmen ausgeht, ist den meisten gar nicht bewusst und kann ihnen oftmals nicht mal übel genommen werden.

Wenn eine Antwort *"not useful"* ist, soll man sie natürlich abwerten. Wenn ein Antwort-Posting aber nützlich ist, obwohl die gestellte Frage nicht beantwortet, sollte man ganz einfach nichts tun.

Nur wenn ein Posting völlig ignoriert was gefragt wurde erscheint mir die Markierung "not an answer" angebracht.